# Google Sheets import issue with limit despite small amount of data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In a Google Sheet we have to format pivot-type capability from two tabs (sub-worksheets) of dat. We ran out of the silly 5 million cells limit in Google fairly quickly. So now we have deleted a lot of the data and have only imported data from our CSV for this year. Since Jan 1.

- In one tab this has 23000 rows with 10 columns of data.
- In the other tab, we have about 1000 rows with 6 rows of data.

We deleted all the data from old tabs, and are importing the new CSVs with "Replace current sheet". When we do this with the much lower limits above...we see this error:

```
Too large to import. Remove rows or columns and try again.
```

What may be going wrong? The main pivot tab also now has most of the data forced by pasting "as value only" from 2020. So it just has one month of data for now to deal with the `ARRAYFORMULA` calculations.

Comment: How manr rows does you csv have? Did you try to import the same csv into an empty Google spreadsheet?